# Knowing visitors identity on shiny R app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Is it possible to count the number of different visitors in an online shiny R app in time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe some kind of labyrinthine system to count visitors, but one of the most used tool is Google Analytics : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html

Answer (score 5):

You could define a reactive counter inside `global.R` that gets increased whenever a user connects and decreased whenever a user disconnects. Here is an example.

```
library(shiny)

# put this line in global.R in case you want to launch the app
# with runApp (from a directory) rather than shinyApp
nvisitors = reactiveVal(0)

server = function(input, output, session){
  nvisitors(isolate(nvisitors()) + 1)
  onSessionEnded(function(x){ 
    nvisitors(isolate(nvisitors()) - 1)
  })

  output$text = renderText({
    nvisitors()
  })
}

ui = shinyUI(
  textOutput("text")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Counting the total number of visitors is more challenging tough since you need to implement [persistent data storage](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) to do that properly.

Comment: I am trying to print the variable in the header inside the UI interface but I am unable: 
header <- dashboardHeader(title = paste("visualisation tool)","online(",output$text,")"))

ERROR: object 'output' not found

Comment: Try `dashboardHeader(title = textOutput("text"))` and adapt the string in `renderText`.