# See who is using a shiny app in a server

Tags: server, shiny, ip

We have created a simple shiny-server and hosting an app for visualization of data.
Is there an easy way to see who is using it? So we can restart it when no one is accessing it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43051537/4357017). This should be enough to see whether there are active users.

Comment: I think I am almost there but will comment on you original post. Thanks!